# Classes in Powershell 5, need help creating $foo.bar.run()

Tags: powershell, oop, powershell-5.0

I seriously apologize for the horrible title of this post...but I'm new to OOP and PowerShell, so I have absolutely no idea how to spell out what I'm asking for. After finding out I could use PowerShell to connect to API's and things like that, I've been working on it non-stop. I'm now working on a script where I need to create a class. I've done this successfully and I'm able to build methods and use them. As of now, all of my objects and methods only have a single level....So if I call a method on an object, it always looks like this $foo.run()

But I want to create something like $foo.bar.run()

I've written a script that uses my TV's API. So currently I have commands like this:

```
$tv.TurnOn()
$tv.TurnOff()
$tv.GetPowerStatus()
$tv.ListInputs()
$tv.GetCurrentInput()
$tv.SetInput($name)
```

But I'd like to be able to do this instead:

```
$tv.Power.On()
$tv.Power.Off()
$tv.Power.Status()
$tv.Input.List()
$tv.Input.Current()
$tv.Input.Set($name)
```

Is this possible?

And yes, I realize there are probably other languages that might be better suited. But I'm just playing around and using this as a transitioning language into actual C# development. For me it's easier to throw a bunch of scripts and parameters into a file and run the file than trying to set up a C# project, compile and test.

Here is the current code for the class:

```
Class VizioTV {
    [String]$IPAddress
    [String]$AuthToken

    [void]TurnOn() {
        Set-Power -action "on" -IPAddress $this.IPAddress -auth $this.AuthToken
    }

    [void]TurnOff() {
        Set-Power -action "off" -IPAddress $this.IPAddress -auth $this.AuthToken
    }

    [String]GetPowerStatus() {
        Return Get-PowerStatus -IPAddress $this.IPAddress -auth $this.AuthToken
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the current class implementation?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Added to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a new class for the `Power` functions and inject the IPAddress and Auth token into a new instance of that class in the constructor of the main class:

```
class VizioTVPower {
    hidden [String]$IPAddress
    hidden [String]$AuthToken

    VizioTVPower([string]$IPAddress, [string]$AuthToken) {
        $this.IPAddress = $IPAddress
        $this.AuthToken = $AuthToken
    }

    [void]TurnOn() {
        Set-Power -action "on" -IPAddress $this.IPAddress -auth $this.AuthToken
    }

    [void]TurnOff() {
        Set-Power -action "off" -IPAddress $this.IPAddress -auth $this.AuthToken
    }

    [String]GetPowerStatus() {
        Return Get-PowerStatus -IPAddress $this.IPAddress -auth $this.AuthToken
    }
}


class VizioTV {
    [String]$IPAddress
    [String]$AuthToken

    [VizioTVPower]$Power

    VizioTV([string]$IPAddress, [string]$AuthToken) {
        $this.IPAddress = $IPAddress
        $this.AuthToken = $AuthToken

        $this.Power = [VizioTVPower]::new($this.IPAddress, $this.AuthToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with this solution. The other solution that Frode provided worked as well, but theirs was displaying the IP and authtoken properties at both levels (TV and TV.Power). I like that yours kept those properties at only the root level. I've got it all written up and it's working great!!! Now my TV turns on when my Xbox One S does, and turns off with it as well. LOL.

Comment: @chadwin cool! I would personally go with a combination of the two FWIW. Mark the `$IPAddress` and `$AuthToken` `hidden` in `VizioTV`, create methods to expose them (like `GetIPAddress()`/`SetIPAddress()`), and then use Frode's injection technique (`[VizioTVPower]::new($this)`)

Answer (score 2):

You could create classes for `Power` and `Input` and store them as properties in your TV-class. Remember to pass a reference to the parent object (TV) so they can access the `IPAddress` and `AuthToken`-values.

```
class VizioTVInput {
    [VizioTV]$TV

    VizioTVInput([VizioTV]$TV) {
        #Keep reference to parent
        $this.TV = $TV
    }

    [string[]]List() {
        return "Something"
    }

    [string]Current() {
        return "Something"
    }

    [void]Set([string]$name) {
        #Do something with $name
    }

}

class VizioTVPower {
    [VizioTV]$TV

    VizioTVPower([VizioTV]$TV) {
        #Keep reference to parent
        $this.TV = $TV
    }

    [void]On() {
        #Remove Write-Host, just used for demo
        Write-Host Set-Power -action "on" -IPAddress $this.TV.IPAddress -auth $this.TV.AuthToken
    }

    [void]Off() {
        Set-Power -action "off" -IPAddress $this.TV.IPAddress -auth $this.TV.AuthToken
    }

    [String]Status() {
        return Get-PowerStatus -IPAddress $this.TV.IPAddress -auth $this.TV.AuthToken
    }

}

Class VizioTV {
    [String]$IPAddress
    [String]$AuthToken

    [VizioTVInput]$Input = [VizioTVInput]::new($this)
    [VizioTVPower]$Power = [VizioTVPower]::new($this)

    #Made it mandatory to input IP and AuthToken. Remove constructor if not needed
    VizioTV([string]$IPAddress,[string]$AuthToken) {
        $this.IPAddress = $IPAddress
        $this.AuthToken = $AuthToken
    }

}

$TV = New-Object VizioTV -ArgumentList "127.0.0.1", "AuthKey123"
```

Demo:

```
$TV.Power.On()
#Outputs
Set-Power -action on -IPAddress 127.0.0.1 -auth AuthKey123

$TV.IPAddress = "10.0.0.1"
$TV.Power.On()
#Outputs
Set-Power -action on -IPAddress 10.0.0.1 -auth AuthKey123
```

Comment: Thanks! I liked your solution as well, but I ended up going with the other one. I like that it kept the IPAddress and AuthToken properties at only the root level when navigating the object tree.

Comment: That was it's biggest weakness. It stored the values as multiple copies. With my approach, you could change them later in one spot and have it updated everywhere. My approach would also let the Power-class access values or methods in the Input-instance++. Choose what works best for you. :-)